# How to Change File Type Associations?

Tags: numbers

How do I stop Numbers from being the default program when a financial file is downloaded or imported?

Comment: Similar: [How can I manually change default applications in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28893/8546) (2011-10-23)

Answer (score 8):

In Finder, choose File > Get Info (or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, or right-click on the file) to change the default application for a particular file:

[image]

And you can also change the association for **all files** of the same type:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)

> A preference pane that allows a user to set the default application used for various URL schemes, file extensions, MIME types, and more.

Easy to use, free, works on Lion and you can do all your file type associations from a single window.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your file, and choose "Get Info".

Under the "Open With" section, choose the program you would like to keep as the default for your file type.

Before closing the window, click the "Change All.." button and confirm your selection in the alert that appears.

There's a quicker way if need you to change the association for select files only. Press <kbd>alt</kbd> after you've right clicked (this turns the `Open With` menu option to `Always Open With`), and then select your preferred application from the pop-up that appears.

[image]

Comment: The "quicker way" changes the association for the selected files only.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Thanks for the clarification - I've made edits.

Answer (score 0):

Download a file, select it in Finder, open the Information dialog and goto "Open width:" section. There you can change the application you want to open a specific file type with. Then click "Change All..." and you're done.