# What is Application Loader and why does it want to open EPUB?

Tags: epub

I just clicked on an EPUB file and instead of Stanza it opened with "Application Loader", which asked me to accept some terms of service.

What is "Application Loader" and can it really be used to display EPUB documents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Application Loader** is the app used to publish content you've created on the App Store. In addition to actual Apps, this also includes ebooks in EPUB format. It's part of Xcode and no, it can't display EPUB documents, so you may want to tell OS X to always open your EPUB documents with Stanza again (this association likely got overwritten when Xcode was last updated).

Answer (score 6):

Application Loader is a developer tool (part of Xcode) that uploads apps to the Mac/iOS App Stores for sale.

See this question for instructions on fixing your file type associations.

- [How to Change File Type Associations?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45491/how-to-change-file-type-associations)

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia [Stanza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexcycle_Stanza) is no longer supported: "According to an email received by a member of the Facebook "Revive Stanza" group, Amazon will no longer be updating or supporting Stanza after version 3.2."

I suggest considering [Calibre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibre_%28software%29). "calibre is free and open source e-book computer software that organizes, saves and manages e-books, supporting a variety of formats"

Comment: Yes, I am using Calibre now. But it is pretty horrible for just a reader (and a Mac app in general). I'd love to just use Preview like I do with PDF.