# Can I get a list of file types a particular app is set as the default to open?

Tags: applications

I would like to see all the file types that a particular application is set as the default for.  I will change some of these default file type associations; I know how to do that on a filetype by filetype basis.  My question is, can I find a list of what file types an app has set itself as the default for so I can do the ones I want all at once?

On this site I found [How can I disassociate a single app (e.g., XCode) from all file types it's mapped to?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79651/how-can-i-disassociate-a-single-app-e-g-xcode-from-all-file-types-its-mappe) which is close to my question but people seem to think it is a duplicate of the change-default-app question (I disagree).  Anyway there is some information there about all associated file types, but unless I misunderstand, nothing about the default-open which is what I am concerned with.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RCDefaultApp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14618/rcdefaultapp) for Mac OS X.  This app adds a "Default Apps" preference pane to your System Settings where you can view and change your Mac's file associations.  Under the hood it interacts with the LaunchServices database.